# What's the order of USB Cables in the male connector of Apple Keyboard with n. Keypad?

Tags: keyboard, usb, repair

The male connector end of my keyboard, Apple Keyboard with numerical keypad, got squeezed beyond repair.

I chopped off that bit and newly stripped the 4 leads: Red, Black, Green & White/Grey.

I'd like to solder these to a new connector.

I'm wondering:

- Is there a "standard" for the order of USB cables globally or for Apple keyboards?
- What's the right order in this product's case?

Comment: Clean down the old connector to ascertain what color wire was soldered to which pinout and put then back them back the same way it was wired to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[USB pinouts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Pinouts) are universal.  So, once you have the IEEE standard used, you should be able to resolder a new connector with no problem.  In this case, the USB connector used on the [Apple Keyboard](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MB110LL/B/apple-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-english-usa) is a USB v1.1 connector.

[image]

I have included the pinouts for USB 1.1/2.0 below for reference.

[image]

Short of that, I am sure you could use the [continuity function](http://en-us.fluke.com/training/training-library/test-tools/digital-multimeters/How-to-test-for-continuity-with-a-digital-multimeter.html) on a multi-meter on a USB cable to figure out which pin goes where

Comment: Thanks for answering. I appreciate the reference image. Can you elaborate on using a multimeter though? How could you use it to figure out the pins?

Comment: It would require removing the back cover of the keyboard.  In USB, it's a straight through config:  pin 1 -> pin 1, pin 2 -> pin 2 and so on.  [You find pin 1 on the keyboard PCB](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66562/identifying-pin-numbers-from-pcb), and continuity test the colored wires to find pin 1.  Once you have it mapped, you can attach a new connector.